# Inhibit all warnings from `make`

Tags: makefile, suppress-warnings

I am building Android AOSP on my server running Ubunty 16.04. I have all dependencies installed and the build completes fine. However, I get many Warnings from the `make` command each time. Is there a way to inhibit those from the console output (eg. via a parameter passed into the command). I have tried with some `gcc` flags in an attempt but the compiler either ignored them or threw errors due to unrecognised parameters.

Thank you for the kind help.
Lorenzo

Comment: What warnings do you get?  Please provide an example (cut and paste not paraphrased) so we know what you're talking about.

Comment: AOSP build warnings are a known issue, especially when you're doing a full build. Additionally, each project within AOSP has its own GCC configuration, so I don't think there's a quick solution... You can modify each project adding flags to silence these warnings, but it will be a pain to maintain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gcc` has the `-w` option which suppresses all warnings. The warning has to be put after any other compiler flags. How you do that depend on the makefile recipes. A late `CXXFLAGS += -w` might work. Put the `-w` behind a by default empty variable and you can override from the make invocation.

Makefile:

```
...
EXTRA_FLAGS ?=
# CXXFLAGS is a convention, your flag variables may be named differently
CXXFLAGS += $(EXTRA_FLAGS)
```

Make invocation

```
make my_target EXTRA_FLAGS="-w"
```

You can also set the environment variable EXTRA_FLAGS to set implicitly for each invocation:

```
export EXTRA_FLAGS="-w"
make my_target
export EXTRA_FLAGS=""
make my_target
```

Caveats include conflict with `-Werror` but guessing you are not using that since it compiles with warnings.